# Can't get back into Windows 8 from Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I had Windows 8 on my laptop and dual booted Ubuntu 13.10 on it using a flashdrive. Something happened with my Windows 8 loader and it doesn't work anymore. It shows up on the grub menu, along with the restorer but neither work. If I select the Windows 8 loader, the screen flashes black and goes right back into the grub menu. If I select the restorer, loads up a background picture with a working cursor (it's not frozen), but I can't do anything from there. My friend suggested using EasyBCD, but I'm not sure how, as I'm "stuck" in this Ubuntu environment that I'm very unfamiliar with. Thanks in advance for reading! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Read the following link which will tell you how to restore the Windows 8 mbr (master boot record) to fix your installation and allow you to boot back into Windows:

http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-fix-windows-8-mbr-master-boot-record/